# Button takes 2 clicks before store update Vue and Pinia

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, pinia

I have been messing around with Vue and trying to learn it. On the first click of the button in LoginForm.vue token and user_data are both null. On the second click it finally gets updated. How can I get the live reactive state of the variables?

I am new to Vue so if there are better common practices please let me know.

store/login.js

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios'


export const useUsers = defineStore('users', {
  state: () => ({
    token: null,
    user_data: null

  }),

  actions: {
    async loginUser(data) {
      try {
        
        let response = await axios.post("users/login", data)
        
        // Object.assign(this.token, response.data.token)
        this.token = response.data.token
        axios.defaults.headers.common['user-token'] = this.token

      } catch (error) {

        return error
      }
    },

    async logout() {
      // Object.assign(this.token, null)
      // Object.assign(this.user_data, null)

      this.token = null
      this.user_data = null
      // localStorage.removeItem('user');
      delete axios.defaults.headers.common['user-token']
    },

    async login_and_get_user_data(data) {
      axios.post("users/login", data).then(response => {
        this.token = response.data.token
        axios.defaults.headers.common['user-token'] = this.token
        axios.get("users/user").then(response2 => {
          this.user_data = response2.data.user
        })
        
      })
    },

    async get_user_data() {
      console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))['token'])
      axios.defaults.headers.common['user-token'] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))['token']

      let response = await axios.get("users/user")

      // Object.assign(this.user_data, response.data.user)
      this.user_data = response.data.user


    }
  }
})
```

components/LoginForm.vue

```js
<script>
import { useUsers } from '@/stores/login'
import { mapActions } from 'pinia'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { isProxy, toRaw } from 'vue';


export default {
    setup() {
        const store = useUsers()
        store.$subscribe((mutation, state) => {
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(state))
        })

    },

    data() {
        return {
            email: "",
            password: ""
        }
    },

    methods: {
        ...mapActions(useUsers, ['loginUser']),
        ...mapActions(useUsers, ['get_user_data']),

        ...mapActions(useUsers, ['logout']),


        on_click() {
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('email', this.email);
            data.append('password', this.password);

            const store = useUsers()
            this.loginUser(data)
            this.get_user_data()
            
            const { token } = storeToRefs(store)
            const { user_data } = storeToRefs(store)
            console.log(token.value)
            console.log(toRaw(user_data.value))        
            
        },

        logout_click() {

            this.logout().then(
                console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')))
            )
            
        }
    }
    
}

</script>

<template>

    <input type="email" v-model="email" placeholder="youremail@mail.com">
    <br>
    <input type="password" v-model="password">
    <br>
    <button @click="on_click">Submit</button>
    <br>
    <button @click="logout_click">Logout</button>

</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `on_click` is calling async methods like `loginUser` or `get_user_data` without waiting them to be finished.
So by the time your are logging `console.log(token.value)` your http request is probably not finished yet and your token is still null.

You need to `await` the methods that are doing those requests.

```js
       async on_click() {
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('email', this.email);
            data.append('password', this.password);

            const store = useUsers()
            await this.loginUser(data)
            await this.get_user_data()
            
            const { token } = storeToRefs(store)
            const { user_data } = storeToRefs(store)
            console.log(token.value)
            console.log(toRaw(user_data.value))        
        },
```

Keep in mind that you will probably need to display a loader to give the user a feedback because the `on_click` is now asynchronous and take a bit more time